# SELECT where IN from another field with comma

Tags: mysql

if I execute this query

```
SELECT user_ids FROM table2 WHERE `id` = 100
```

I get a comma separated list  : 12,45,268  , user_ids is a varchar(255) field

if I execute this query

```
SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE group_id IN(12,45,268)
```

I get what I want

but I need

```
SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE group_id IN
(SELECT user_ids FROM table2 WHERE `id` = 100 );
```

but I get only user_id(s) from id = 12

maybe a problem of conversion between varchar(255) and comma separated integer id ?

thanks for helping

Comment: How many rows you getting when executing SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE group_id IN(12,45,268)

Comment: I get exactly my result , it works perfectly of course , it s a very basic query , I get all users from the 3 group_id  : 12,45,268

with the last query only users from group_id = 12

Comment: Then, same result you will be getting when excute last query(inside sub query)

Comment: yes but it doesnt work otherwise why should I ask it ?

Comment: ok. Are you checking in php or directly in mysql db?

Comment: i've got the answer thanks !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [MySQL INSTR() Function](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_mysql_instr.asp). Try this instead:

```
SELECT user_id FROM table1 WHERE 
INSTR((SELECT user_ids FROM table2 WHERE `id` = 100 LIMIT 1),group_id)>0;
```